# Matlab: Intersection of 2 Lines

Tags: matlab

How could I find the intersection point of 2 lines that reach to each other along of them? (Matlab) (`polyxpoly` doesn't work for this condition).
For example, How could I find the intersection point of these lines:

```
%Line 1:
x1=[1,2]; y1=[1,3];
%Line 2:
x2=[1,1]; y2=[1,2];
```

Comment: Your question declares points that form a special case with an **infinite slope** (line 2). So the straight-forward approach using `polyfit` or the calculation of slopes to get the intersection won't work. See this post on [Matlab Central](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2011/09/08/intersecting-lines-part-2/) for a possible solution!

Comment: This is more a (basic) Algebra problem than a programming problem

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=matlab+intersection+of+two+lines+stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](http://geomalgorithms.com/a02-_lines.html) page, or even better, [this](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/91primitives/) page, for the math you're looking for. It also has examples (though for C, not matlab)